# RGBDSLAM_V2: Undefined reference

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, catkin, ros-hydro, rgbdslam-v2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying to use RGBDSLAM_V2 on ARM and get this strange error when I run catkin_make:

```
...
[ 90%] Building CXX object rgbdslam_v2/CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/transformation_estimation.o
[ 92%] Building CXX object rgbdslam_v2/CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/header.o
[ 94%] Building CXX object rgbdslam_v2/CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/covariance_estimation.o
[ 96%] Building CXX object rgbdslam_v2/CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/feature_adjuster.o
[ 98%] Building CXX object rgbdslam_v2/CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/aorb.o
[100%] Building CXX object rgbdslam_v2/CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/features.o
In file included from /opt/ros/hydro/include/opencv2/flann/kmeans_index.h:50:0,
                 from /opt/ros/hydro/include/opencv2/flann/all_indices.h:38,
                 from /opt/ros/hydro/include/opencv2/flann/flann_base.hpp:44,
                 from /opt/ros/hydro/include/opencv2/flann/flann.hpp:50,
                 from /opt/ros/hydro/include/opencv/cv.h:69,
                 from /home/pb1/catkin_ws/src/rgbdslam_v2/src/features.cpp:16:
/opt/ros/hydro/include/opencv2/flann/logger.h:73:9: note: the mangling of 'va_list' has changed in GCC 4.4
Linking CXX executable /home/pb1/catkin_ws/devel/lib/rgbdslam/rgbdslam
CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/misc.o: In function `g2o2QMatrix(g2o::SE3Quat)':
/home/pb1/catkin_ws/src/rgbdslam_v2/src/misc.cpp:81: undefined reference to `QMatrix4x4::QMatrix4x4(double const*)'
CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/graph_manager.o: In function `QMatrix4x4 eigenTF2QMatrix<Eigen::Transform<double, 3, 1, 0> >(Eigen::Transform<double, 3, 1, 0> const&)':
/home/pb1/catkin_ws/src/rgbdslam_v2/src/misc.h:44: undefined reference to `QMatrix4x4::QMatrix4x4(double const*)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/pb1/catkin_ws/devel/lib/rgbdslam/rgbdslam] Error 1
make[1]: *** [rgbdslam_v2/CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make" failed
```

Any idea how to fix this? I'd really appreciate it. Before doing this, I did change the typedef of `qreal` in Qt from float to double on my system - could that be causing any issues here?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195421/rgbdslam_v2:-undefined-reference/) by [AndrewLawson](https://answers.ros.org/users/11631/andrewlawson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-10-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is almost certainly caused by changing the definition of qreal.

The [QMatrix4x4 constructor](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmatrix4x4.html) in question takes a `qreal *`. Since the QT library was compiled with one definition of qreal, and you've now changed the header to have a different definition, the linker is now looking for the wrong function in the QT library.

The lesson here is that you shouldn't modify the installed headers.

If you REALLY, REALLY, REALLY want to change the definition of qreal, you'll need to build all of QT from source with your changes. Beware that if you install a modified version of QT as the default, anything that was linked against the stock version will probably no longer work.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0